# How do I get the Printer status?

Tags: c++, c, linux, point-of-sale, network-printers

Is there any way I can get the printer status, like paper jam or out of paper, from a Network Printer?

I'm working on a project to print from a Point of Sales into a A4 Network Printer, I'm planning to use the LPR native application but I can't get the paper jam or out of paper errors using that application.

Is possible to get those status from a Lexmark Network Printer?

Does exist any C/C++ Open Source library that allow me to get those status?

Thank you in advance

Comment: [link](http://www.library.georgetown.edu/laptop-printing) Check the Link May be useful to you for further enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the printer. Most of the LAN enabled boxes do have a web-interface which is an easy catch. I did the same for some ricoh printers using curl to download status pages and parsed those...

Another possibility would be using snmp traps as printers tend to have events for 'paper jam' or 'low on ink/toner'...

Answer (score 0):

The only solution possible for something like that is a protocol that the printer uses that allows you to connect to it and request data. If, for example, it is an IPDS capable printer, you will have to find out what port it uses and connect to it using TCP/IP sockets, request the Sense Data, then decipher it. That's about all you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if the printer you have supports the UPnP Device Control Protocol PrinterBasic and/or PrinterEnhanced. Typically a DLNA-certified printer has this.

You can check out the specs sheet is here:
http://upnp.org/sdcps-and-certification/standards/sdcps/
Basically, the interface between your device and your controller app will be SOAP-based.

There are UPnP SDKs available, but you will need to study the rigorous UPnP architecture to implement it. 
Good luck!